# Cytochrome Oxidase activity in neuronal cells

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, neuroscience, neurophysiology, cellular-respiration

The abstract of [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166223689901653?showall%3Dtrue%26via%3Dihub) article says

"...the entire neuron is often not metabolically homogeneous; most of the oxidative activity is usually found in dendrites."

Why would the activity of cytochrome oxidase be localized in the dendrites of the cell? Is it because it has a greater surface area (more channels and such) compared to the rest of the cell?

Comment: How would oxidative activity mean only cytochrome c oxidase? It could mean more oxidation of glucose, which could be due to presence of more channels in dendrites than axon.

Comment: @Metroplex I do not know, the article is talking specifically about histo- and cytochemical methods for mapping activity of cytochrome oxidase. I do not have access to the full article (I'm working on finding it), but I thought asking "where's the full article" would be an inappropriate question.